# Laravel Violates not-null constraint with default value

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am having an issue with Laravel and default values. I created the field in my table like so:

```
$table->string('title', 255)->default('');
```

And in the model, I have a default set again using this:

```
 protected $attributes = [
        'title' => '',
    ];
```

Yet I am always getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column
>   "title" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains
>   (3dd07c7a-e3f3-4f20-8d16-0f066b219dc2, dsfs, sdfs, null, null, null,
>   sdfs, null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, null, null). (SQL: insert into
>   "users" ("title", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "business_unit",
>   "linkedin_profile") values (, dsfs, sdfs, sdfs, , ) returning
>   "user_id")

My abbreviated save action (example without validation) is the following:

```
$data = Input::all();
$user = new Users($data);
$user->save();
```

The following is the $data:

```
array (size=12)
  '_token' => string '0EI9JGmgiNDAqmv83pdQZaktyWNLiX3GB9JQSfvA' (length=40)
  'first_name' => string 'ads' (length=3)
  'last_name' => string 'asd' (length=3)
  'email' => string 'asd' (length=3)
  'title' => null
  'business_unit' => null
  'linkedin_profile' => null
  'is_admin' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_employee' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_manager' => string '0' (length=1)
  'is_trainer' => string '0' (length=1)
  'rt' => string '/users' (length=6)
```

How come my default value is not being set?

Comment: protected $attributes = [
        'title' => null,
    ];

Comment: Can you show us the code where you create/save your model?

Comment: You don't even need to set a default value in your model.  Eloquent wouldn't send `title` if you didn't have it in your attributes and then it would fall back to the MySQL default.

Comment: @ChinLeung I updated the question with how I am saving.

Comment: @DevinDixon is `$data['title']` set to null?

Comment: @Devon Its set to empty ([title] => )

Comment: @DevinDixon, that doesn't really distinguish between null or an empty string.  Use var_dump, dd, or a real debugger to get the actual data type.

Comment: Show us your data: `dd(Input::all());` Laravel converts empty strings to null in the request.

Comment: @Devon it is this: 'title' => null . Chin Leung is correct

Comment: @ChinLeung I updated the data. Why is null causing the issue?

Comment: @DevinDixon The database default only works when the value is missing , here it's not missing, it's just null. Perhaps a hacky `array_filter($data)` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your database column does not allow null values for title.

You can allow them like this:

```
$table->string('title')->nullable()->default('');
```

Or even without the default to have it as `NULL` by default:

```
$table->string('title')->nullable();
```

Otherwise, you have to make sure your title is not null.

---

If you don't want to allow null values and convert it automatically to empty string, you can add a mutator like this to your model:

```
public function setTitleAttribute($title)
{
    $this->attributes['title'] = is_null($title) ? '' : $title;
}
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

Comment: So there is not an elegant way that is already built into the model that will allow the default to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Because the 'title' key is in the provided array, it'll try to insert it: you should be able to insert null values.

You could use a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) `setTitleAttribute($val)` method in your Model class, or simply unset the 'title' array key if the value is empty before inserting. You could also filter using collection helpers or array_filter to remove unset all null values.